# Rails application not loading scss

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I tried many things but my navbar is not showing properly on browser, just because sccs is not loading. This application was a Rails API Application and I converted to regular application. Maybe something went wrong on this process.

```
Assets/Stylesheets/application.scss
// Your CSS partials
@import "components/index";
```

```
Assets/Stylesheets/Components/_index.scss
// Import your components CSS files here.
@import "navbar";
```

```
Assets/Stylesheets/Components/_navbar.scss
```

```
Environments/development.rb
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.quiet = true
  config.assets.compile = true
```

```
application.rb
require_relative 'boot'
require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module RailsJwt
  class Application < Rails::Application
    
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.0

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.
  end
end
```

I am new here so I don't know which other parts of my application I should show.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you post anything else that's in your `application.scss` file? Do you know if you're using Sprockets or Webpacker? Can you post which version of Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you converted an API-only Rails application to use CSS I'm assuming you haven't configured Webpacker to handle your front end assets. This link may be helpful: https://onrails.blog/2020/02/20/using-css-in-rails-6/

The most important for you is probably adding the following to your `app/views/application.html.erb` file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
```

If you're using Webpacker, adjust accordingly. Also, I don't think Rails 6 ships with the `sprockets` gem so you may have to add that to your Gemfile, unless you plan on using Webpacker.